# After upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 20.10 my laptop keyboard and mouse are not working

Tags: keyboard, mousepad, 20.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 20.10 my laptop keyboard and mouse are not working. How do I fix it? Please help me.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem as you when I boot my system from 20.10 on a USB drive on my laptop.

Comment: Some times an Ubuntu upgrade will make your system useless.  This happened to me attempting to go from 16.04 to 18.04.  Never again!  My suggestion costs a bit of money but, well worth it.  Have a spare system, a couple spare hard drives and if a laptop is involved, an extra hard drive for it.  Do the upgrade first on a spare system.  I acutally skipped Ubuntu 18 because of some issues. Never install a major release directly onto a 'production' system.  For a laptop, consider doing a new install on that extra laptop harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

using Linux Kernel v5.4 instead of 5.8 seems to fix the issue for me.

```
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-52-generic
```

**edit**

I've installed Kernel 5.8.16 and yes the keyboard and touch mouse works very well.

```
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ uname -r
5.8.16-050816-generic
```

**edit**

I recommend anyone facing the same issue to mark that on [launchpad bug link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1902156), so it can draw more attention from developers.